# Асинхронная функция из синхронной в Python и discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, asyncio

В моём дискорд-боте необходимо вызвать асинхронную функцию из синхронной, т.к. функция `play` voice_client'а принимает только синхронный коллбек. Т.к. сама библиотека Discord.py асинхронная, в ней уже есть свой event loop, поэтому решения использовать функции `asyncio.run`, `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe`, `loop.run_until_complete` у меня применить не получилось. Подскажите, что делать?

UPD. Функция коллбека у меня с рекурсией, вот так:

```
def player(...):
    ...
    voice_client.play(..., after=player)
    ...
```

`asyncio.get_running_loop()` выдаёт ошибку - нет цикла событий в текущем потоке

Comment: Что именно с `loop.run_until_complete` не получилось? loop через `loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()` получали?

Comment: [Я случайно создал две учётные записи, как их объединить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: По вопросу - из ошибки следует, что колбэк запущен в отдельном потоке, и теоретически можно просто в этом потоке запустить новый эвент-луп через `loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()`

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас вызывается синхронная функция из корунтинной функции-обработчика команды дискорд бота, и в этой синхронной функции вызывается ещё и другая асинхронная функция - то её нужно вызывать через `asyncio.gather(*tasks)`. На вход подаются собранные корунтины.